# Using Framer Motion to animate path to the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I've got a "link" icon that I am using to explore SVG animation using Framer.

I'm animating the path from 0 initially, to 1 once animated, which does what I want it to; it animates from the start to the end and then from the end back to the start.

Next, I want to try and see what it would look like if I then animated the icon disappearing from the start to the end. This would work in a similar fashion to how it currently works, except it would make the path disappear from the start rather than the end.

So far, I have this:

```
export default function App() {
  const transition = {
    duration: 2,
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatType: "reverse",
    ease: "easeInOut"
  };

  return (
    <svg
      height="256"
      width="256"
      fill="none"
      stroke="currentColor"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <motion.path
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeWidth={2}
        d="M13.828 10.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0l-4 4a4 4 0 105.656 5.656l1.102-1.101m-.758-4.899a4 4 0 005.656 0l4-4a4 4 0 00-5.656-5.656l-1.1 1.1"
        initial={{ pathLength: 0 }}
        animate={{ pathLength: 1 }}
        transition={transition}
      />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

And a CodeSandbox link; https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-burnell-kc6gt

I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to change to get the path to animate out from the start to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate `pathOffset` on your motion path from 0 to 1 to animate out from the start to the end.

But you'll need some way to switch between the two animations. So you'd need to orchestrate the animations with [Animation Controls](https://www.framer.com/docs/utilities/#animationcontrols), or switch the `animation` prop based on some other event in your code.

Here's an example that animates in as you have it, then animates out with `pathOffset` when the icon is clicked:
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-wu-lbocl?file=/src/App.js